# Casting to template type

Tags: c++, syntax

What is this syntax Prof. Stroustrup uses in his book The C++ Programming Language 4th ed. while describing hash and equality functions on page 917.

```
std::hash<int>{}(variable) //variable is of type int
```

Is that a casting from int to hash ? But why those flower brackets after hash? I know that placing them after a variable default initializes it. As for as casting is concerned we normally cast like say double (int)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets break `std::hash<int>{}(variable)` down into its components:

- `std::hash<int>` - This is the type, it's a specific type of [standard hash template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).
- `{}` - This creates an instance of the `std::hash<int>` class.
- `(variable)` - This calls the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) on the instance previously created, passing `variable` as argument.

After the expression, the instance of the `std::hash<int>` object is destructed.

For example:

```
std::size_t hash = std::hash<int>{}(variable);
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
std::size_t hash;
{
    std::hash<int> hashing_temporary_object;
    hash = hashing_temporary_object(variable);
    // The above call is equal to hashing_temporary_object.operator()(variable)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps explain brace-initialization.

Comment: I had to read that twice. For a second I thought it was a function definition. :) Nice answer.

Comment: I thought that that syntax meant function style casting explained elsewhere in his book till you came along and mentioned that hash template has a function call operator.

Answer (score 1):

`std::hash` is a class template.  `<int>` provides template arguments to the template.  `std::hash<int>` together is the type produced by a specialization of the class template.  `std::hash<int>{}` default-constructs a value of that type.  `std::hash<int>{}(variable)` calls the class's `operator()` to evaluate the hash for a given number.

Answer (score 0):

`std::hash<int>{}` creates a function object.
As you say the "flowery" or even curly braces initialise this.

You then call the function with the `int`.